# Differences between parallelism and multiple apps in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am planning to dynamically scale up/down a Flink app. The app consumes events from Kafka using the kafka-flink connector.

Since the "warm up" of the app takes few minutes (caching...) and changing parallelism level involves restarts, I prefer to submit (scale up) or alternatively kill (scale down) tasks instead of changing the parallelism level.

I wonder from performance, logic and execution plan, are there any differences between this approach and the Flink built-in parallel execution?

In other words, what would be the differences between 10 identical Flink tasks to one task with parallelism level = 10 ( env.setParallelism(10) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parallelism will determent if the task is  **[Redistributing or not](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows)**

- One-to-one streams (for example between the Source and the map()
  operators in the figure above) preserve the partitioning and ordering
  of the elements. That means that subtask[1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows) of the map() operator
  will see the same elements in the same order as they were produced by
  subtask[1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows) of the Source operator.
- Redistributing streams (as between map() and keyBy/window above, as
  well as between keyBy/window and Sink) change the partitioning of
  streams. Each operator subtask sends data to different target
  subtasks, depending on the selected transformation. Examples are
  keyBy() (which re-partitions by hashing the key), broadcast(), or
  rebalance() (which re-partitions randomly). In a redistributing
  exchange the ordering among the elements is only preserved within
  each pair of sending and receiving subtasks (for example, subtask[1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows)
  of map() and subtask[2] of keyBy/window). So in this example, the
  ordering within each key is preserved, but the parallelism does
  introduce non-determinism regarding the order in which the aggregated
  results for different keys arrive at the sink.